# Devise and OmniAuth: How to save facebook data for later use?

Tags: facebook, openid, devise, omniauth

I have successfully implemented login with Facebook using Devise and OmniAuth (built into Devise). Now I need to figure out how to store the user's name in the database so that I can display their name for other users to see that they created/edited records in my application.

I must have copied this code from somewhere, and it looks like it should be working, but it is definitely not saving the name in the database:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
      @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

      if @user.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      else
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

   def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token['extra']['user_hash']
    if user = User.find_by_email(data['email'])
      if user.first_name != data['first_name']
        user.update_attributes :first_name => data['first_name']
      end
      user
    else # Create an user with a stub password. 
      User.create!(:email => data['email'], 
                   :first_name => data['first_name'],
                   :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session['devise.facebook_data'] && session['devise.facebook_data']['extra']['user_hash']
        user.email = data['email']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew, as written [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html): the method attr_accessible makes the attribute available for mass assignment.

You should put it like this:

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name
```

Comment: You are right. I didn't realize I had an `attr_accessible` call. I figured this out a while ago, but forgot to answer my own question. Thanks!